# Output binary buffer with STL

Tags: c++, stl, binary, queue

I'm trying to use something that could best be described as a binary output queue. In short, one thread will fill a queue with binary data and another will pop this data from the queue, sending it to a client socket.

What's the best way to do this with STL? I'm looking for something like std::queue but for many items at a time.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using streams?

Comment: Technically speaking no, but I prefer not to involve the giant boost, which I assume is what you meant?

Comment: This is not really an answer, but have you thought about making your own queue to handle the data instead of using STL?

Comment: I was talking about std::ostream, actually.

Comment: @Dennis Miller: why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @TreDubZedd, can std::ostream really stream data into a non-blocking win32 socket?

Comment: @Dima: I would be worried about performance issues when dealing with streaming binary data. 

@monoceres: Please let me know if this works, as I deal with a lot of binary data as well. I'm interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does "binary data" mean?  Just memory buffers?  Do you want to be able push/pop one buffer at a time?  Then you should wrap a buffer into a class, or use `std::vector<char>`, and push/pop them onto `std::deque`.

Comment: Won't inserting data to the beginning of the vector be terrible inefficient?

Comment: You can use vector::reserve() to allocate the memory in the vector, and then copy your data into it.  In the end, it depends on how the data are generated.  You can keep them in vectors from the beginning.

Comment: I think I will try this out. Hopefully I won't get any performance problems and I do, I will rethink this later.

Comment: Yes, inserting data at the beginning of a vector is inefficient. Use a `std::deque<char>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I've needed this sort of thing for a network communications system in a multi-threaded environment.

In my case I just wrapped std::queue with an object that handled locking (std::queue is not thread-safe, generally speaking). The objects in the queue were just very lightweight wrappers over char*-style arrays.

Those wrappers also provided the following member functions which I find extremely useful.

```
insertByte(unsigned int location, char value)
insertWord(unsigned int location, int value)
insertLong(unsigned int location, long value)
getByte/Word/Long(unsigned int location)
```

These were particularly useful in this context, since the word and long values had to be byteswapped, and I could isolate that issue to the class that actually handled it at the end.

There were some slightly strange things we were doing with "larger than 4 byte" chunks of the binary data, which I thought at the time would prevent us from using std::vector, although these days I would just use it and play around with &vector[x].

Comment: I guess this would work, but it would be nice to get all the data as one contiguous byte array (like vector).

Comment: Indeed, in my case the "binary data" consisted of a large number of 1,2 and 4 byte fields packed together for transmission. The above isn't really appropriate for... for example, an image. :)

Comment: I'm going with a vector, maybe the performance will not suffer.